# Field value too long (3184658 characters), use form data

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, nestjs-config

This is my field in DTO

```
@IsNotEmpty({ message: 'Nội dung này không được để trống!' })
@IsString()
@MinLength(0, { message: 'Độ dài bài viết không hợp lệ!' })
content: string;
```

I have not set a maximum limit for this field, but when transmitting a large string of 3184658 characters an error occurred

```
"statusCode": 400,
"message": "Field value too long",
"error": "Bad Request"
```

If the error is due to DTO, the error code will usually be 422 (not 400). I tried reconfiguring my      middleware but it's not work

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }));
```

Because Form-Data.
Is there any way to remove the limit for formdata?

Comment: When you speak of "DTO" is there a database involved? Maybe that field exceeds a length limit in the database? You probably will have to debug your backend to see where that error is coming from.

Comment: Nah, my dto is used to validate before going to the service first, then to the database. This means the 400 error was blocked before being sent to the DTO

Comment: Just because the total limit for the entire JSON payload is 10MB doesn't necessarily mean that a single field has the same limit.

Comment: are you using multer?

Comment: yes, but when I entered a regular field (not a file field, it's fine) then when I reached a large amount of characters I got an error message

Answer (score 0):

you need to increase the field data limit in multer module:

```js
MulterModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        //...your config,
        limits: {
          fieldSize: parseInt(process.env.MAX_FIELD_SIZE), //default 1MB
          //in my case using limit file size and file number
          fileSize: parseInt(process.env.MAX_SIZE_PER_FILE_UPLOAD),
          files: parseInt(process.env.MAX_NUMBER_FILE_UPLOAD),
        },
      }),
    }),
```